# why $V= V_{q_1} \cap ....\cap V_{q_n} ? $ why not $V= V_{q_1} \cup ....\cup V_{q_n} ?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness

I have some confusion in Baby  **Rudin** book

My confusion is given marked in red box[image]

**My confusion**:  why $V= V_{q_1} \cap ....\cap V_{q_n} ? $ why not  $V= V_{q_1} \cup ....\cup V_{q_n} ?$

My attempt :  I thinks  we can write $V= V_{q_1} \cup ....\cup V_{q_n} $ because aribtrary union of open set are open

Comment: The union may intersect $W$, but not the intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are after a neighborhood of $p$ which does not intersect$$W=W_{q_1}\cup W_{q_2}\cup\cdots\cup W_{q_n}.$$And, although $V_{q_1}\cup V_{q_2}\cup\cdots\cup V_{q_n}$ is indeed a neighborhood of $p$, there is no reason to suppose that it does not intersect $W$. On the other hand, $V_{q_1}\cap V_{q_2}\cap\cdots\cap V_{q_n}$ is also a neighborhood of $p$ and, furthermore, it is sure that it does not intersect $W$.